# Is there an equivalent of ? : operator of C# in Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I want to write the following C# code equivalent in JavaScript/jQuery

```
(x == 0 && y < 0 ? x : x+y)
```

Is there an equivalent shorthand way such as above in JavaScript/jQuery or will I have to write the whole if else.

I need to put such a condition in the for loop definition,

```
for (i=0; i< (x == 0 && y < 0 ? x-y : x+y); i++)
```

and thus was wondering if there is a way I could do something similar in JavaScript. As far as I know, I will have to write an if else, compute the value and then use that value. But perhaps somebody knows a better way?

Comment: You should have just tested.

Comment: whenever you learn a new language, the first thing you should read are the operators. read the reference before posting

Comment: If `x == 0` then you might as well just have `-y` instead of `x-y`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the ternary operator also exists in Javascript.

The code you posted

```
for (i=0; i< (x == 0 && y < 0 ? x-y : x+y); i++)
```

will work, verbatim.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know it was called as ternary operator.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
for (i=0; i< (x == 0 && y < 0 ? x-y : x+y); i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is originally a c/c++ operator. As far as I can remember this operator is available in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Please think of the maint. programmers and rethink this a little.

Why not something like this:

```
var countTo=0;
if( x == 0 && y < 0 )
    countTo = x-y;
else
    countTo = x+y;

for (i=0; i< countTo; i++){
}
```

While it may be a couple extra lines of code it is much more readable, and maintainable, and is far better at expressing your intent then a cryptic inline if inside a for loop declaration!